# JavaScript - Disabling Textbox upon Change of Drop Down List Index

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu, textbox

I have the following code which suppoesedly disables or enables a textbox depending on the value in a drop down list.

Now this is how I am making a reference to this code from the drop down lists:

Unfortunately, the code is generating an exception.  I believe that I am using the wrong event handler, that is, OnSelectedIndexChanged.  How can I remedy the situation please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) replace **OnSelectedIndexChanged** with **onchange**

and

2) replace

**var DropDown_Total = document.getElementById("DropDown_Total")**

with

**var DropDown_Total = document.getElementById("<%= DropDown_Total.ClientID %>")**

for all getElementById

3) replace **(DropDown_Date.options[DropDown_Date.selectedIndex].value**
with
**(DropDown_Date.options[DropDown_Date.selectedIndex].text** for both dropdown

try this it's working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DisableEnable() {
        var DropDown_Total = document.getElementById("<%= DropDown_Total.ClientID %>")
        var Textbox_Total = document.getElementById("<%= Textbox_Total.ClientID %>")
        var DropDown_Date = document.getElementById("<%= DropDown_Date.ClientID %>")
        var Textbox_Date = document.getElementById("<%= Textbox_Date.ClientID %>")

        if (DropDown_Total.options[DropDown_Total.selectedIndex].text == "Any Amount") {

            Textbox_Total.disabled = true;
        }

        else {
            Textbox_Total.disabled = false;
        }

        if (DropDown_Date.options[DropDown_Date.selectedIndex].text == "Any Date") {
            Textbox_Date.disabled = true;
        }

        else {
            Textbox_Date.disabled = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

html

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Textbox_Total" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Textbox_Date" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown_Total" runat="server" onchange="DisableEnable();">
    <asp:ListItem>Any Amount</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Exact Amount</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Below Amount</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Above Amount</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown_Date" runat="server" onchange="DisableEnable();">
    <asp:ListItem>Any Date</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Exact Date</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Before</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>After</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use onchange event which will work for javascript function calling. OnSelectedIndexChanged is server side event.

Comment: @Raghubat like this?  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown_Total" runat="server" onchange="DisableEnable()">

Comment: yes.. if u r using master page then code for getting a control is :      var DropDown_Total = document.getElementById('<%= DropDown_Total.ClientID %>');

Answer (score 1):

just replace `OnSelectedIndexChanged`  with `onchange` because onchange is handled by js. `OnSelectedIndexChanged` is handled by code behind.

Comment: I tried the suggestion but although no exception is generated, the textboxes are not being grayed out.

Comment: can you post a fiddle link?

and make sure your code lines

var DropDown_Total = document.getElementById("DropDown_Total")
         returns proper value.

sometimes cotrol id renders differently HTML.

Comment: I have never used fiddle link before.  Give me a minute to set up an account.

Comment: Here is the fiddle link :)

Comment: that was a js fiddle. you can use http://www.coderun.com/ide/

meanwhile please check whether your var DropDown_Total have any value??

put an alert or use console.log('put value here')

Comment: yes it works perfectly now :)  As a matter of fact, the textbox gets disabled when I put the dropdown list to Any Price/Date and enabled again when I put it to another value.

Comment: alright good. And Just for your future reference use ClientIDMode="Static" property of server controls to avoid writing "<%= DropDown_Total.ClientID %>" :)

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial: how to disable/enable textbox using `DropDownList` in Javascript

In this function we pass dropdownlist id and textbox id as parameter in js function

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function DisableEnableTxtbox(DropDown, txtbox) {

        if (DropDown.options[DropDown.selectedIndex].text == "free") {

            txtbox.disabled = true;
        }

        else {
            txtbox.disabled = false;
        }

    }
  </script>
```

Now add the following code:

```
 <td align="center" class="line">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_MonP1" runat="server" CssClass="ppup2"   onchange="DisableEnableTxtbox(this,txt_MonP1);"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_MonP1" runat="server" CssClass="ppup" placeholder="Subject"></asp:TextBox>
       </td>
```